# Splitting string using .split

Tags: java, split, delimiter

```
String test = "a,b|c,d|e,f";
```

How do I split the string test using .split method to make it become

```
arrayList.get(0); // ans is a
arrayList.get(1); // ans is c
arrayList.get(2); // ans is e

arrayList1.get(0); // ans is b
arrayList1.get(1); // ans is d
arrayList1.get(2); // ans is f
```

Comment: what have you tried? Try to find the pattern of how they are distributed on the two lists... its not that hard

Comment: i have splited them into (a,b) (c,d) (e,f)

Comment: yes and now you just need to split them again and distribute them onto the two lists ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
for(String pair : text.split("[|]")) {
    String[] parts = pair.split(",", 2);
    arrayList.add(parts[0]);
    arrayList1.add(parts[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
String s[] = "a,b|c,d|e,f".split("[,\\|]");
```

this way the even index(0, 2, 4) will contain `a, c, d` and odd index(1, 3, 5) will contain `b, d, f`. Now create two `ArrayList` and add them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use \\W for any non-word character splitting

```
test.split("\\W");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try lik ethis:

```
String str[] = "a,b|c,d|e,f".split("[,\\|]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
split("|");
```

to have

```
arr[]={"a,b","c,d","e,f"}
```

.

Then you can split each string with `split(",");` to have

```
a1[]={"a","b"}
a2[]={"c","d"}
a3[]={"e","f"}
```

Now put the first element of a1, a2, a3 in arrayList and the second in arrayList1  .